# Combining two videos next to each other leads to an ffmpeg exit error

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to combine two videos next to each other I'm getting an error:

> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Filter overlay has an unconnected output

This is my code so far:

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

const firstx = secondx = 1280
const firsty = secondy = 600

 ffmpeg("./input1.mp4")
.input('./input2.mp4')
.complexFilter([
    `[0:v]scale=${firstx}:${firsty}[0scaled]`,
    `[1:v]scale=${secondx}:${secondy}[1scaled]`,
    `[0scaled]pad=${firstx+secondx}:${firsty}[0padded]`,
    `[0padded][1scaled]overlay=shortest=1:x=${firstx}[output]`
])
.outputOption(["-map"])
.output("./out.mp4")
.on("progress",({percent})=>{
    console.log(`prossing video: ${percent}%`)
})
.run()
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `[output]` and `.outputOption(["-map"])`.
- Or provide the filtergraph output label to `-map` option, such as `-map "[output]"`.

See [FFmpeg Documentation: Stream Selection - Complex Filtergraphs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs-1).